# Save user form input to model and display in view ("Object reference not set to an instance of an object")

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Edit;

Sharing the code as it looks after some changes aswell as with the right variable names etc.

So I have an input form that looks like this:

```
@model InluppEtt.Models.UserInfo

@using (Html.BeginForm("Hello", "Second", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Age)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Age)

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Location)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Location)

    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
}

@Html.DisplayName(Model.DisplayInfo)
```

It supposed to get posted to this action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Hello(UserInfo userInfo)
    {
        var ui = new UserInfo()
        {
            Name = userInfo.Name,
            Age = userInfo.Age,
            Location = userInfo.Location
        };

        ViewBag.Message = "Success";
        return View("Hello", ui);
    }
```

Now I am trying to save the input into this model here but I am unable to make it work it seems.

```
public class UserInfo
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Age { get; set; }
    public String Location { get; set; }

    public String DisplayInfo
    {
        get
        {
            return "Name: " + Name + " Age: "
                + Age + " Location: " + Location;
        }

    }
}
```

I am trying to show the data underneath the form in the view but as I visit that page the first thing I get is an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error at the

```
@Html.DisplayName(Model.DisplayInfo)
```

Thanks

Comment: This is a bit confusing. your `Html.BeginForm()` has no action name or method and still the form is posted. you are using a model but not using a model binding. besides, inside your `Hello` action you are creating an instance of your model and saving  the values directly from `Request`. so you are already saving them. are you trying to send that instance to another view? and what is `@Model.DisplayText`? you mean `@Html.DisplayText` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**
view:

```
@model Test.Models.UserInfo
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Hello";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Hello", "Test"))
{
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Age)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Age)

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Location)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Location)

    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
}

@ViewBag.Message
<br />
@Html.DisplayName(Model.DisplayInfo)
```

controller:

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Test.Models;

namespace Test.Controllers
{
    public class TestController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Hello(UserInfo userInfo)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(userInfo.Name))
                ViewBag.Message = "Success";
            return View(userInfo);
        }
    }
}
```

model:

```
using System;

namespace Test.Models
{
    public class UserInfo
    {
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public String Age { get; set; }
        public String Location { get; set; }

        public String DisplayInfo => "Name: " + Name + " Age: " + Age + " Location: " + Location;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it seems promising but the @Html.DisplayName causes a null reference exception

Comment: There shouldn't be any null reference. `return View("location_to_your_cshtml_view_file", displayInfo);` in this line you are passing the model so your view will surely recognize it, if you do not pass `displayInfo` here only then you should get null reference. you can also use `View(displayInfo);` if your view page is automatically recognized by the action method.

Comment: see the edited version. you never told the input form and view were same. next time you post a question you be crystal clear about what you have and what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because you(DefaultModelBinder) are accessing object without initializing it into your view GET Request. I hope there is no object instantiation in your `[httpget]` of ActionMethod. You need to instantiate first then pass to your ActionMethod get request and this will show empty string (what value types are initialized to default).

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Hello(UserInfo userInfo)
{
    var ui = new UserInfo();
    return View("Hello", ui);
}
```